# Why is my Blazor code giving a Namespace not found error?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I was following along with the Blazor with Johan and was stuck on the following bit of code. I copied his code that was working verbatim and for some reason I'm getting the Namespace not found error. Something which I cannot figure our why as my code seems correct. For reference here is the code but it is incredibly frustrating.

```
@using AnimalShelterApp
@page "/animal"
<h3>Animal</h3>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <!-- This is the Image tag -->
    <img src="@CurrentAnimal.PictureURL" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <!-- This is the Body of the Card -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">@CurrentAnimal.Name</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
            @if (CurrentAnimal.AnimalKind == "Dog")
            {
                @: I'm a @CurrentAnimal.Gender dog that is @CurrentAnimal.EstimatedAge years old.
            }else
            {
                @: I'm a @CurrentAnimal.Gender cat that is @CurrentAnimal.EstimatedAge years old.
            }


        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public Animal CurrentAnimal { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        CurrentAnimal = new Animal
        {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Max",
                AnimalKind = "Dog",
                EstimatedAge = 1,
                PictureURL = "https://pixabay.com/images/id-2785074/",
                Gender = "Male",

            };
    }
}
```

[image: my solution]

Comment: Is your namespace the same as his (AnimalShelterApp)?

Comment: Yes, it is. My namespace does seem to be the same

Comment: Have you declared the Animal class somewhere in your solution? Because from the picture provided I cannot see any Models folder or Animal.cs

Comment: Yes, I do have a animal class file.

Comment: I think I figured out what my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

## I needed to add the class to reference it.

```html
namespace AnimalShelterApp.Pages
{
    public class Animal
    {

                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
                public string AnimalKind { get; set; } = string.Empty;
                public int EstimatedAge { get; set; }
                public string PictureURL { get; set; } = string.Empty;
                public string Gender { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    };
}
```

When I inserted the relevant class I could instantiate a new Animal object. This made it so I did not get my Namespace error.

As it was I was trying to instantiate a class that did not exist. So we learn. It has been a while since I did any C#. I'm a bit rusty.